# What does "go on my tires" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes, word-play

From the movie [To Wong Foo, Thanks for Everything! Julie Newmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Wong_Foo,_Thanks_for_Everything!_Julie_Newmar)

In a drag queen contest, a muscular man passes the winner envelope to a past drag queen, who says to the audience of the muscular man:

> I don't know who he is, but if there's a snowstorm tonight, he is **going on my tires**.

I am assuming this is a way to joke about the man's physical attractiveness.

Comment: My guess: snowy weather requires travelling in cars with snow tires. In the event of a sudden snow storm some cars will be equipped with the correct tires and some will not. People who lack safe transport might be given a ride home by people with snow tires. So interpret as "I'll give him a ride home!". With more than a hint of suggestiveness in the "ride".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a play on words.  In snow, we often use [**stud tires**](https://www.tirebuyer.com/education/studded-winter-tires) (or *studded tires*) - tires with small metal studs embedded in them for extra traction.

[Stud is also a slang term for a sexually attractive man.](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/stud)

So the play on words goes:
In the snow we put studs on our tires : I am going to put him on my tires :: He is a stud.

Answer (score 4):

It also is a reference to the chain harness the muscular guy is wearing. Chain used to be put on tires in a similar fashion but was outlawed in most places because it caused road damage. You can still use them in places that receive excessive yearly snowfall, like in the Rockies in certain places.

This is what snow chains look like when put on tires:

[image: A car wheel with chains on it]

Comment: Welcome to ELL Jodie! Knowing the guy was wearing a chain harness makes the joke make a lot more sense. I’ve edited your answer to make it a little more learner friendly. Feel free to roll back my edits if you don’t care for them.